# Conditional probability of multiple coin flips

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I flip $9$ fair coins. There are more heads than tails. What is the probability all flips resulted in heads?

> Since coins are fair, probability of more heads is the same as more tails, therefore $p = 0.5$. Let's call the event where all $9$ flips are heads H. Does that mean the conditional probability I mentioned is $2P(H)$?

Comment: Hint: condition on the number of heads and tails (the event 'more heads than tails' branches into 5 cases: 5 heads 4 tails, 6 heads 3 tails, ..., 9 heads 0 tails.)

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the event of all heads is $A$.  You want $\mathsf P(A\mid H)$.

You have argued that $\mathsf P(H)=1/2$, because $\sum_{t=5}^9\binom 9t=\sum_{h=5}^9\binom 9h$ . The count of outcomes for five or more tails equals the count of outcomes for five or more heads. Indeed, however **this also means** the count of equiprobable outcomes in event $H$ is: $$\sum_{h=5}^9\binom 9h = 2^8$$

Now there is only one outcome where all flips show heads, and this is a subset of event $H$.  Thus: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid H) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap H)}{\mathsf P(H)}\\&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(H)}\\&=\dfrac{1/2^9}{1/2}\\&=\dfrac{1}{2^8}\end{align}$$

---

**Note** This is $\mathsf P(A\mid H)=2\mathsf P(A)$ rather than $2\mathsf P(H)$.